# String.replace() function to parse XML string so that it can be displayed in HTML

Tags: html, xml, actionscript-3, pattern-matching, replace

I have a XML string which needs to be displayed within HTML. I understand the first thing needed to be done here is to convert all '<' and '>' into '& lt;' and '& gt;' (ignore the space after & sign). This is what I am doing to replace '<' -

```
regExp = new RegExp("/</g");
xmlString = xmlString.replace(regExp, '& lt;');
```

`xmlString` does not change.

Also, `trace(regExp.test("<"));` prints `false`.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the way you create your RegExp object.

Because your using the RegExp constructor, don't include the `/` characters:

```
regExp = new RegExp("<", "g");
```

or use `/` as a shortcut:

```
regExp = /</g;
```

See this page for more details: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/RegExp.html

Answer (score 3):

replace returns a new string, it doesn't modify the old one. So if you want to overwrite the old you have to do the following:

```
xmlString = xmlString.replace(regExp, '&lt;');
```

Or if you don't want to overwrite the old one, just store the result in a new variable.

```
var newString = xmlString.replace(regExp, '&lt;');
```

Comment: Yes, I know String.replace() does not modify the original string. My concern is why `trace(regExp.test("<"));` prints `false`.

Comment: Ah, my apologies, when I was testing it out myself I didn't bother to store the regex in a variable (I just put the /</g itself in the replace)